# I can't understand how to use 'ANY' in Document Type Definition language

Tags: xml, dtd, any

Suppose we have this XML document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<!DOCTYPE note [

<!ELEMENT note (to,from,heading,body, foo)>
<!ELEMENT to (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT from (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT heading (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT body (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT foo ANY>

]>

<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
<foo><stuff>test</stuff></foo>
</note>
```

I'm using the ANY keyword for the element "foo" but I get an error saying

```
Line 20, Column 16: element "stuff" undefined
```

from this site http://validator.w3.org/check

why is this happening? isn't any supposed to accept any kind of parsable data in the foo element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ANY` means "Any element type defined in the DTD" not "Any element type the author cares to invent".

From [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-logical-struct):

> The declaration matches ANY, and the content (after replacing any entity references with their replacement text) consists of character data, CDATA sections, comments, PIs and child elements **whose types have been declared**.

(My emphasis)